Integration by parts involving the function $|x|^{-2}$.
Let $N \geq 5$, consider $B \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be the unit ball and take $u \in C^\infty_0(B)$. I am trying to understand the following equality
$$
\int_B u^2 \Delta \left(1 - |x|^{-2} \right) dx = \int_B \left( 1 - |x|^{-2} \right) \Delta(u^2) dx,
$$
what is in a paper I am reading. Apparently it is true because $N \geq 2$ implies $|x|^{-2} \in L^2(B)$ (this is what the authors write). This problem can be reduced to
$$
\int_B u^2 \left(1 - |x|^{-2} \right)_{x_i x_i} dx = \int_B \left(1 - |x|^{-2} \right) (u^2)_{x_i x_i} dx,
$$
or even to
$$
\int_B u^2 \left(1-|x|^{-2} \right)_{x_i} dx = \int_B \left(1-|x|^{-2} \right) (u^2)_{x_i} dx.
$$
I tried to use the usual integration by parts formula. However, as of course $1/|x|^2 \not\in C^1(B) \cap C(\overline{B})$, I don't know if this is the best way to go. For $x \neq 0$ I know
$$
(1-|x|^{-2})_{x_i} = -2|x|^{-4}x_i.
$$
So I tried to prove without integration by parts that
$$
\int_B u^2 (-2|x|^{-4}x_i) dx = \int_B \left(1-|x|^{-2} \right) (u^2)_{x_i} dx,
$$
but I failed. I know as $N \geq 5$, both sides of last identity are finite, because $u$ is bunded, so we don't need to use Holder inequality. Any help is welcome.

Giving a look at the paper the functions are in $H^2 \cap H^1_0$.As such the  Laplacian is intended in the weak sense. What you have written is the definition of the weak derivative. You can't integrate by parts not continuous functions

Thank you. But can I take $1 - |x|^{-2}$ as a test function ?

I think $1-|x|^{-2}$ is in $H^1_0(B)$ for $N \geq 7$, because under this hypothesis, $(1-|x|^{-2})_{x_i}, 1-|x|^{-2} \in L^2(B)$.

Let $f(x) = |x|^{-2}$ and notice that  $f \in L^1(B)$ for $N \geq 3$. Also
$$
f_{x_i}(x) = -2|x|^{-4}x_i \in L^1(B) \text{ for } N \geq 4
$$
and
$$
|f_{x_i x_j}(x)| \leq  2(N-4)|x|^{-4} \in L^1(B) \text{ for } N \geq 5.
$$
Therefore $f \in W^{2,1}(B)$ for $N \geq 5$ and so, by Theorem 3, p. 266 from Evans's book of PDE's, there exists $f_n \in C^\infty(\overline{B})$ such that $\|f_n - f\|_{W^{2,1}(B)} \to 0.$ Now
$$
\int_B \Delta f_n u^2 dx = \int_B f_n \Delta(u^2) dx.
$$
Now, as $u$ is bounded, we can take the limit as $n \to \infty$ and use the $L^1(B)$ convergence in order to obtain
$$
\int_B \Delta f u^2 dx = \int_B f \Delta(u^2) dx.
$$

Let $f(x)=|x|^{-2}$, $\rho_\epsilon$ a mollifier over $B$. We have $f * \rho_\epsilon \to
 f$ uniformly (as $f$ is continuous) and $f*\rho_\epsilon$ is smooth.
By the property of the convolution we have $(\Delta f)*\rho_\epsilon= \Delta( f * \rho_\epsilon)$
By integrating by part (as both the function are smooth), we get, for any $\epsilon$
$$
\int_B \Delta(f*\rho_\epsilon) u^2 dx= \int_B f*\rho_\epsilon \Delta u^2dx
$$
By uniformly convergence theorem we get
$$
\int_B \Delta f(x) u^2(x) dx= \int_B f(x) \Delta u^2 (x)dx
$$

Thank you. I am afraid that the discontinuity of the function $f$ in the origem could cause some problems. I tried to find the result you used and I found Theorem 8.14 from Folland, Real Analysis: Modern Techniques, where the boundedness of $f$ is required.
